# How to edit a previously defined function in ipython without scrolling all the way back

Tags: python, ipython

If I'm using ipython and define my own function, say

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1
```

and later decide that I would like to edit this function to

```
def f(x,m,c):
    return m*x + c
```

is there a quick way to access the function code without scrolling back with the arrows?

Comment: If you start re-typing the line, then Ctrl-p will scroll you through the previous lines that match.

Answer (score 2):

As @RuthC has pointed out, within IPython there is a pretty cool way to edit a previously defined function. If you partially type in the first part of your def, e.g. `def`, `def myf`, or `def myfunc`, you can then press Ctl+P to scroll through various defs in your current session. The really cool thing about this mode is that the entire function definition can be retrieved and you can use up and down arrow keys to edit specific lines of your function definition.

For longer functions, you might prefer to edit a .py script in your favorite editor and use the [`%run`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#%run) magic command within iPython to rerun it

in myscript.py

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1
```

in iPython:

```
In [1] %run myscript.py

In [2] f(1)
Out[2] 2
```

Oh wait. I want to make a change (and save!) myscript.py

```
def f(x,m,c):
    return m*x + c
```

Back to iPython

```
In [3] %run myscript.py

In [4] f(1,2,3)
Out[4] 5
```

Comment: thanks, that's useful. I feel that the comment **If you start re-typing the line, then Ctrl-p will scroll you through the previous lines that match**, is also useful information in the context of this post. If you could add that to the post as well please that'd be good